# Sql Management Studio 2016 could not load type

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I just upgraded to SQL Management Studio 2016 CTP2

I get this error when logging into a db server:

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.FailedOperationException' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. (ObjectExplorer)

Here is the info in the about tab:

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   13.0.500.53

Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 13.0.500.53

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  10.0.10586.0

Microsoft MSXML                          3.0 6.0

Microsoft Internet Explorer              9.11.10586.0

Microsoft .NET Framework                 4.0.30319.42000

Operating System                         6.3.10586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with an old pre-release version when the [RTM version of SQL Server 2016 is available as a free download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)?

Comment: I followed the upgrade prompt from the application itself.