# Could not create SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I'm running SSIS on a Windows server 2016. When I try to create a new SSIS package I get the following error message,

```
Could not load type
'microsoft.sqlserver.management.UI.WizardManager13' from assembly
'Microsoft.SqlServer.WizardFramework.dll, Version 14.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
```

The dll exists in the following directories

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.WizardFramework.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.WizardFramework\13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.WizardFramework.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.WizardFramework\14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.WizardFramework.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\temp\Q549EA29CC\Microsoft.SqlServer.WizardFramework.dll
```

How can a create a SSIS package?

Comment: Are you trying to create a package using visual studio or sql server managment studio or else?

Comment: Give more details about what you mean by "try to create a new package".   What steps exactly are you doing to get this error?   Sounds like you need to repair your installation of SQL Server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880222/sql-management-studio-2016-could-not-load-type

Comment: I have a Windows Server 2016 where I've installed SQL Server 2016 and VisualStudio 2015 with Data Tools. Now in a remote desktop I open a SSIS project. Then Solution Explorer -> SSIS Packeges -> New SSIS Package gives me the above mentined error messege. I also noteced that I get the same message when I try to create a new SSIS project.

Comment: I've also tried to reinstall Visual Studio, but the same error occurs.

Comment: Was this project that you are loading originally created on the same version of Visual Studio as the version you are using now?   What happens if you create a new project?   Are you able to add packages to it?

Comment: It was created in Visual Studio 2013, though I get the same error when I try to create a new project. But, yes I'm able to  add packages to my existing project.